# SQL to entities - complex query selecting dates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework code-first and I want to query the appointments table in my database selecting:

1. All the appointments on given dates

   ```
   public IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAppointments(IEnumerable<DateTime> datesWithEverything)
   {
       using (OneClickContext context = new OneClickContext())
       {
           var query = from e in context.AppointmentSet
                       where datesWithEverything.Contains(e.StartDate)
                       select e;
           return query;
       }
   }
   ```
2. I also need **only one** appointment from any other day, the first found for each day not included in the given dates.

The reason for this, is that my calendar component will be able to show in bold the days containing at least one appointment, but I don't want to load thousands of appointments since I will be looking few days (with all the details) per request.

Is this possible hitting the database once?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please share sample data and table structure to work on

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly, you are getting all appointment data for a range of dates, and then you simply need to know all other dates that have at least one appointment in order to bold them.  You aren't actually using the appointment data on those other dates just yet.  Is that correct?

You are right to try to limit the number of trips to the database, but you need to balance that with not returning more data than you actually need.  If I understand right and all you need are dates with appointments, you should use a second query:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesWithAppointments()
{
    using (OneClickContext context = new OneClickContext())
    {
        var query = (from e in context.AppointmentSet
                    order by e.StartDate
                    select e.StartDate).Distinct();
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Also, it's a matter of style but the variable "query" is not needed, and you can simply:

```
return (from e in context.AppointmentSet
        order by e.StartDate
        select e.StartDate).Distinct().ToList();
```

Note the `ToList()`.  Linq query execution is deferred until the first time it is enumerated and your query context is declared in a using block.  You must execute the query before the using block exits in this case.

On edit, since you require an actual appointment, you should be able to get what you want in a single trip using linq's union and grouping.  Union will automatically remove any duplicate entries.

```
public IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAppointments(IEnumerable<DateTime> datesWithEverything)
{
    using (OneClickContext context = new OneClickContext())
    {
        var query = from e in context.AppointmentSet
                    where datesWithEverything.Contains(e.StartDate)
                    select e;

        query = query.Union(from e in context.AppointmentSet
                           group e by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.StartDate) into grp
                           select grp.FirstOrDefault());

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do actually need the appointment data on those other dates. If I get the dates I need to create fake appointments in order to bind them (MVVM). I was wondering if I could do it with a single trip to the database.

Comment: Thank you Dimitri for your time. Unfortunately since I'm using a SQLite database, APPLY Joins are not supported.